# Use a custom product-image.php file in woocommerce product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new in Woocommerce. I would like to customize the template for the product page of Woocommerce just for the books category. I replaced the content-single-product.php file with a custom one modifying the code in single-product.php file like this:

```
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php 
                global $post;
                $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) $categories[] = $term->slug;
                if ( in_array( 'livros', $categories ) ) {
                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-books' );              
                } else {
                    wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );                
                }
                ?>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Now I want to do the same in replacing the product-image.php file with this one product-image-books.php. Tried like this but not working:

```
global $post;
            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) $categories[] = $term->slug;
            if ( in_array( 'books', $categories ) ) {
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product-books' );
                wc_get_template_part( 'single-product/product', 'image-books' );
            } else {
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product-image' );
            }
            ?>
```

This file is in the template folder: woocommerce > single-product. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single product images are displayed using `woocommerce_show_product_images()` function & hooked via `woocommerce_before_single_product_summary` hook.

So instead of calling template directly, first remove the action from that hook and then add your custom function on the same hook.

Your files to show images (`product-image-books.php` & `product-image.php`) must be with in `wordpress\wp-content\themes\your-theme\woocommerce\single-product\` directory.

Please add below code in your theme's `functions.php` file or custom plugin file. I have tested the code & it's working fine in my installation.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'qt563_woocommerce_show_product_images', 20 );

function qt563_woocommerce_show_product_images() {
    global $post;
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) $categories[] = $term->slug;
    if ( in_array( 'livros', $categories ) ) {
        wc_get_template( 'single-product/product-image-books.php' );              
    } else {
        wc_get_template( 'single-product/product-image.php' );                
    }
}
```

@Emmanu, Can you please verify & accept it as answer?

Comment: Worked file! Thanks @Sarath :)